# How would you recover a corrupt Firestore database to the point of failure?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, disaster-recovery

Firestore's `export` and `import` services enable you to recover a corrupt database to some point prior to your desired recovery time. But how would you roll the database forward from there to the actual point of failure?

Would you have to develop your own recovery process, together with transaction-logging arrangements to drive this?

As an example of why you might need this, imagine you've just been informed that a Junior member of your IT staff, thinking they were deleting a collection of test data from the company's Firestore database has actually deleted the company's Customer_Details collection.

You have a copy of the collection from the last time your automated Export ran - but this is now a fortnight old and your company has been acquiring new customers through its online transaction site at a rapid rate. There are no paper records for these customers. You are sunk!

In your previous employment, you'd used a SQL database that automatically created log files that would allow you to recover a corrupted database to its point of failure by reloading it from a dump and then rolling it forward. Firestore doesn't appear to have an equivalent facility. If so, how could you have designed your system to replicate this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is what you called [Cloud Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) which handles events in Cloud Firestore with no need to update client code.

You can attempt to write the new update to Firestore. If it succeeds, your `.then` can resolve the promise and the function can end. If it fails, add some lines to the `.catch` to update the document with `change.before.data()`

Below is the sample code:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

admin.initializeApp();

const firestore = admin.firestore();

exports.myFunction = functions.firestore
  .document('myCollection/{myDocumentId}')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {

  const newValue = change.after.data();
  const oldValue = change.before.data();

  let myChanges = {
    // Update a value
  };

  return change.after.ref.update(myChanges)
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Document updated successfully');
      return Promise.resolve();
    })
    .catch(() => {
      // The update failed and the document needs to be rolled back
      return change.before.ref.set(oldValue);
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('Document was rolled back');
      return Promise.resolve();
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      return Promise.reject(err);
    });
});
```

The document will then return to its previous value.

---

**For Firestore Backups:**

There are various ways to trigger Cloud Firestore backups:

1. [Datastore Import/Export UI](https://console.cloud.google.com/firestore/import-export)
2. [Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#gcloud)
3. [exportDocuments API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases/exportDocuments)
4. [Scheduled data exports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export)

---

You can also develop your own recovery process by using [Cloud Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs).

Steps to create your own recovery process:

1. **[Create Cloud Storage Bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets)**. *(You can skip these if you already have.)*
2. **Create the Cloud Workflow definition to execute Firestore export API call.**

   - To define a workflow, go to [Cloud Workflows](https://console.cloud.google.com/workflows) page.

     - You will be prompted to Enable the Cloud Workflows API if you haven’t done so for your project. Make sure after you enabled the API, you open the console again.
     - On the Cloud Workflow Dashboard, hit Create.
     - Set a workflow name and description: e.g. `firestoreExportDocuments`
     - Choose region: e.g. `us-central1`. Hit Next.
     - You will notice there is a service account preselected, remember that. It may have the form of
       xxxxxxxxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
     - On the next page, paste the below snippet, edit the path to your bucket on line 5.

       ```
       - initialize:
           assign:
             - project: ${sys.get_env("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID")}
             - firestoreDatabaseId: (default)
             - firestoreBackupBucket: gs://my_bucket_for_backups
       - exportFirestoreDatabaseAll:
           call: http.post
           args:
             url: ${"https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/"+project+"/databases/"+firestoreDatabaseId+":exportDocuments"}
             auth:
               type: OAuth2
             body:
               outputUriPrefix: ${firestoreBackupBucket}
           result: result
       - returnResult:
           return: ${result}
       ```
     - Click Deploy. Your workflow will get deployed.
3. **Setup IAM permissions to execute the Cloud Workflow.**

   - Go to IAM Permissions page, and identify the service account from the list. Choose from the right menu the Edit option.

     - Add the following permissions:

       - Cloud Datastore Import Export Admin: Full access to manage imports and exports.
       - Storage Object Creator: Access to create objects in GCS.
       - Workflow Invoker: Access to execute workflows and manage the executions.

   *At this time, you can execute your workflow. The workflow status will show succeeded status when the workflow was able to trigger the Firestore export/backup process.*
4. **Setup the invocation via Cloud Scheduler**

   - Go to [Cloud Scheduler](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudscheduler) page, enable the API if prompted, and revisit the Scheduler page.
   - To crate a scheduled job, hit Create Job:

     - Use a name and description for your scheduler. e.g.: `workflows-datastore-export-backup`
     - For midnight trigger use this syntax: `0 0 * * *`. *You can generate cron schedules [here](https://crontab.guru/)*.
     - In the Target selector choose: `HTTP` as method choose `POST`
     - Enter the below URL:
       `https://workflowexecutions.googleapis.com/v1beta/projects/<PROJECT-ID>/locations/us-central1/workflows/<WORKFLOW_NAME>/executions`
     - Replace the placeholders.
     - In Show more section, configure Auth header: `OAuth`, and add your service account previously used, and for Scope use:
       `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform`
     - Leave other selections with their default selections.
5. **Run the scheduler**.

   - On the [Cloud Scheduler](https://console.cloud.google.com/cloudscheduler) entries, hit Run now.
   - A successful export is logged to [Firestore/Datastore Import/Export](https://console.cloud.google.com/firestore/import-export) page.

The output is on your selected Cloud Storage bucket and the format is not self readable, files are packet into many parts and there is a manifest file that resembles the schema and format. To import/restore backups to a Firestore/Datastore instance, you can do that manually from the [Datastore Import/Export UI](https://console.cloud.google.com/firestore/import-export).

---

UPDATE:

**You could also use [Scheduled data exports](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export) as you mentioned. I included it on the options above.**

Based on the scenarios given, once you delete a document in Firestore, the documents are gone for good. Currently, there is no undelete feature but there's a way you can implement an undo feature. If you have a function that deletes a document, you have to modify the delete function to not actually delete the document, and instead just update the UI to remove the view. You would have to schedule the deletion to happen some time later. The undo option would then just restore the visibility of the deleted document and cancel the delayed deletion.

Also, it is highly recommended to consider adding a new boolean field to the document to mark that it's deleted or not, and use that in a filter for the query you pass to FirebaseUI. The field would have to be present on every document in order for it to filter correctly. After the UI is done, you would then have to figure out how to actually delete all the documents you marked for deletion in the UI.

I'd also recommend to create a [Feature Request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features) if you want to have this kind of feature.

Comment: So, I think you're agreeing with my understanding that Firestore has no built-in mechanism for this (I was wondering if anyone might point me in the direction of Audit Logging and explain how these could help out). I agree that if you have to create your own logfiles, functions are the way to go, but I think you underestimate the implications for your system design. Have a think about how you would code the recovery job!

Comment: I think this is a serious problem that merits more attention. I've added a bit of drama to the question in the hope that this might help it attract a bit more interest..

Comment: Incidentally, Google has updated its documentation on automating Firestore export using pubsub - see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/schedule-export. This works a treat.

Comment: Hi @MartinJ, I've updated my answer and btw, thank you for mentioning `schedule-exports`. I already included it on my answer.

Comment: When I first began to think about this problem I was locked into a **transaction-logging** mindset. This was as much because I was thinking as much about "auditing" as about "recovery". The problem with this model though is that recovery would involve replaying the original application code - hence my suggestion that I thought you were underestimating the attendant complication. But I now realise that what you're proposing is the creation of **after looks** on the monitored collection which can then be re-applied blindly.

Comment: In short, I'm not entirely convinced that there aren't cases where this approach will lead to problems, but I'm going to spend some time now trying it out anyway. Keep an eye on this thread because I'll get back to you with the results. In the interim, I cheerfully accept your solution. Many thanks for your hard work.

Comment: Is it possible to select specific collections with the Workflow approach?